# run shell script from php as a specified user

Tags: php, linux, shell, xampp, daemon

I am trying to run a shell script from a PHP script.

PHP code :

```
<? php
     $sss = escapeshellarg('virtualbox');
     $result = shell_exec("/home/hani/Desktop/launchscript.sh '$sss' 2>&1 ");
     echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
     echo "<br />";
     echo (shell_exec('whoami'));
?>
```

my shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash


sss=$1
echo 'the sudo password' |sudo -S service $1 restart
```

After I run the PHP code in a web server (Xampp), I got this output :

```
[sudo] password for daemon: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for daemon: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt

daemon
```

Although, I haven't set any password for the **daemon** user.
And after I checked  the current user running the PHP code I found it is **daemon**.
After many researches here and in the net, I found that **daemon** can't run `sudo` commands.
I also found that I can fix this by editing the sudoers file and giving permissions to the daemon user to run sudo commands. However this is not a secured solution.
so my question is : **How to run that script via the PHP code but not as a daemon?**
**PS** : I tried this in order to change the current user running the PHP file :

```
$result = shell_exec(" sudo -u hani /home/hani/Desktop/launchscript.sh '$sss' 2>&1 ");
```

But I got this  output in the browser :

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

and the user remains daemon.

I am using Xampp in Ubuntu 16.04
Another information, I run this command in the terminal to know the owner of the 'httpd' service :

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

the output is : **daemon**

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that i already run this : sudo chmod +x myshellscript .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a solution ( but still not sure about the security issues).
It only needs to change the default **user** (owner) and **group** of the *httpd* service. This can be done by editing the `httpd.conf` located in `/opt/lampp/etc` (if you are using Xampp). The default user, as I mentioned in the question, is daemon. However it has not permissions to run sudo commands, so it only needs to change that user by another one who has the permissions to run sudo commands (obviously the ***root*** user or ***your deafult user*** in Ubuntu).

Comment: Hello I have daemon issue. My python script is fine in terminal but failed in symfony framewrok. Please help me

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

a better way is give daemon access to run the one particular script you want

edit the sudoers file

`sudo visudo`

add in the following line (change the path to the script you want to run)

`daemon ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/ubuntu/scripts/script.sh`